# How long can Google ARCore Geospatial Anchors be stored for?

Tags: arcore

I'm trying to find any information about how long Google ARCore Geospatial Anchors can be stored for but couldn't find it anywhere in the documentations.

It was mentioned that Persistent Cloud Anchors can be resolved for a period from 1 day to 365 days after they are created. Would it be the same case for Geospatial Anchors? Thanks.